# Convexity of quadratic functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, positive-semidefinite

I am new to the field of optimization and keep encountering objective functions of the form

$$f(x) = \frac 12  x^T A x - b^T x + c$$

Just wanted to know the reasoning behind some properties of the function above.

1. I know if $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite (PSD), then $f(x)$ is convex. Can $A$ be PSD and non-symmetric and $f(x)$ still be convex? How is being symmetric related to being convex? For example $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\-1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ is positive definite (PD) but not symmetric. Is $f(x)$ convex still? Most books list Hessian of the function being PSD to be a sufficient condition for $f$ to be a convex function.
2. If $A$ is not symmetric and PSD, then does $f(x)$ still have a global minimum?

Comment: If $A$ is not symmetric then consider equivalent representation for the quadratic form $x^TAx=0.5x^T(A+A^T)x$ with the symmetric matrix.

Comment: @A.Γ.do you mean we can have a convex function with only $A$ being psd/pd and $A$ not being symmetric?

Comment: Normally the matrix $A$ is assumed to be symmetric, it is a part of the definition of being sign definite e.g. psd. No need to work with nonsymmetric matrices in context of quadratic forms as you can easily  symmetrize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $A$ is not symmetric, $x^TAx = \frac12 x^T (A + A^T)x$, so the problem is equivalent.
2. For convex functions, a local minimum is a global minimum, so yes, there still exists a global minimum.

Comment: Almost correct. There is no guarantee a global minimum exists without stronger conditions; e.g., $A$ is positive _definite_. It's possible $f(x)$ is unbounded below if $b^Tv\neq 0$ for any $v$ in the null space of $A$.

Comment: @Michael Grant can you please elaborate on the boundness of this function. For instance if $A$ is both symmetric and positive definite, is it possible for $f(x)$ to be unbounded below?

Comment: If it is positive _definite_, then $f(x)$ is definitely bounded. If it is positive _semidefinite_, then it _may_ be unbounded below, but it depends on whether or not $b$ is in the range of $A$.